# How to use BroadcastReceiver for sending email in Android ?

Tags: java, android, email, alarmmanager

I'm trying to create alarm manager to send an email for particular date in my application . I have use BroadcastReceiver for send email at particular date and time.I want that when the user click my app "send" button it should send the email for particular date and time.Can some one help me please .It's urgent.Thanks to appreciate.

Here is my Activity Code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.form_details);

         etServiceName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_ServiceName);
         etSupplierName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_SupplierName);
         etEmailId = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Edittext_EmailId);
         etReplacementDate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText_ReplacementDate);
         etInterval_Days = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText_IntervalDays);
         etNextReplanishmentDate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Next_Replanishment_Date);

        // Get current date by calender
         final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         year  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
         month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
         day   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


         etReplacementDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showDialog(DATE_OF_REPLACEMENT);
            }
        });



            etInterval_Days.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     String fixedDate = etReplacementDate.getText().toString().trim();
                     SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MM-yyyy" );
                       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                       try
                       {
                                cal.setTime( dateFormat1.parse( fixedDate ) );
                       } 
                       catch (ParseException e) 
                       {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                       }

                       String strNumDays = etInterval_Days.getText().toString().trim();
                       if(strNumDays.trim().length()>0)
                       {
                           try
                              { 
                                  intConvertDays =Integer.valueOf(strNumDays);
                              }
                              catch(NumberFormatException ne)
                              {
                                 System.out.println("could not parse :: " +ne);
                              }

                       }


                       cal.add( Calendar.DATE, intConvertDays );
                       Date dated = cal.getTime();
                       String beforDate_String = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(dated);
                       System.out.println("beforDate_String: " + beforDate_String);
                       etNextReplanishmentDate.setText(beforDate_String);

                       cal.add( Calendar.DATE, -2 );
                       Date minusDate = cal.getTime();
                       strMinusDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(minusDate);
                       System.out.println("String strMinusDate : " + strMinusDate);


                       if(strMinusDate.trim().length()>0)
                       {
                           try
                              { 
                                IntMinusDate =Integer.valueOf(strMinusDate);
                                System.out.println(" IntMinusDate = " + IntMinusDate);
                              }
                              catch(NumberFormatException ne)
                              {
                                 System.out.println("could not parse :: " +ne);
                              }

                       }


                }
            });


         Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(Xyz.this, EmailSendTask.class);

         // create the object
         final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

         final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,(int) IntMinusDate,  intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);




         btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
         btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 strEmail= etEmailId.getText().toString().trim();

                         strServiceName =  etServiceName.getText().toString().trim();
                         strSuppliername= etSupplierName.getText().toString().trim();
                         strReplacementDate= etReplacementDate.getText().toString().trim();
                         strIntervalDays= etInterval_Days.getText().toString().trim();
                         strNextReplacementDate = etNextReplanishmentDate.getText().toString().trim();
                         System.out.println("Data :- " + strServiceName +","+ strSuppliername +","+ strEmail +","+ strReplacementDate +","+ strIntervalDays + "," + strNextReplacementDate);

                         SharedPreferences sharedPref =getSharedPreferences("MyPref_Email", 0);
                         SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = sharedPref.edit();

                         editor1.putString("ServiceName", strServiceName);
                         editor1.putString("Suppliername", strSuppliername);
                         editor1.putString("Email", strEmail);
                         editor1.putString("ReplacementDate", strReplacementDate);
                         editor1.putString("IntervalDays", strIntervalDays);
                         editor1.putString("NextReplacementDate", strNextReplacementDate);

                         editor1.commit();
                         Log.e("Commit is Complit", "Save");

                         //sendEmail();
                         System.out.println("Email Has To Be Sent Successfully");

                         databaseHelper.insertServicenDetails(strServiceName, strSuppliername, strEmail, strReplacementDate, strIntervalDays, strNextReplacementDate);
                         System.out.println("Data Has Been Save Successfully");


                        //set the alarm for particular time
                         alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,IntMinusDate, pIntent);
                         System.out.println("set the alarm for particular time  : ");

             }
        });
}
```

Here is my BroadcastReceiver Code

```
public class EmailSendTask extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    String strServiceName;
    String strSuppliername;
    String strEmail;
    String strReplacementDate;
    String strIntervalDays;
    String strNextReplacementDate;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref_CellNumber", 
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = prefs.edit();

         strServiceName=prefs.getString("ServiceName" , "a\n");
         strSuppliername=prefs.getString("Suppliername" , "a\n");
         strEmail=prefs.getString("Email" , "a\n");
         strReplacementDate=prefs.getString("ReplacementDate" , "a\n");
         strIntervalDays=prefs.getString("IntervalDays" , "a\n");
         strNextReplacementDate=prefs.getString("NextReplacementDate" , "a\n");

         Log.e("ON CREATE" , "=" + strServiceName);
         Log.e("ON CREATE" , "=" + strSuppliername);
         Log.e("ON CREATE" , "=" + strEmail);
         Log.e("ON CREATE" , "=" + strReplacementDate);
         Log.e("ON CREATE" , "=" + strIntervalDays);
         Log.e("ON CREATE" , "=" + strNextReplacementDate);

                            String subject = strServiceName;

                            String body = strServiceName+","
                                          +strSuppliername+","
                                          +strReplacementDate+","
                                          +strIntervalDays+","
                                          +strNextReplacementDate;

                           Log.e("body " , " = " + body);

                          Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                          i.setType("message/rfc822");
                          i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{strEmail});
                          i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                          i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , body);
                          i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                          try 
                          {
                              context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail...in Service Background"));    

                          } 
                          catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) 
                          {
                              Toast.makeText(context, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          }
    }


}
```

Here is log cat Error

```
08-19 11:39:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(485): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 11:39:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(485): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.demo.EmailSendTask: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
08-19 11:39:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1805)
08-19 11:39:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-19 11:39:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
08-19 11:39:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-19 11:39:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-19 11:39:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-19 11:39:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 11:39:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-19 11:39:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-19 11:39:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-19 11:39:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-19 11:39:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(485): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
08-19 11:39:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:621)
08-19 11:39:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:258)
08-19 11:39:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:258)
08-19 11:39:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at com.demo.EmailSendTask.onReceive(EmailSendTask.java:63)
08-19 11:39:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1794)
08-19 11:39:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0):

**INVINCIBLE android tell all the things**

## just you have to make ur eyes open ..

*caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?*

The logcat tells you what the problem is in the first line

```
Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag
```

add that flag

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, maven.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
c.startActivity(i);
parentActivity.finish();
```

You can get a list of all available `Intent Flags` [here in the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: :- Thanks for the reply , sorry but i didn't get you.I don't understand what is Intent i = new Intent(context, maven.class);c.startActivity(i);.Actually i didn't get where is to place this code.

Comment: u just need to add a flag while doing the intent

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by that Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is lost. Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail...in Service Background") will generate a new intent, so we should set it again. see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.L_preview/android/content/Intent.java#Intent.createChooser%28android.content.Intent%2Cjava.lang.CharSequence%29

Try code below

```
try 
{
    Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail...in Service Background");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);    

} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){
    Toast.makeText(context, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```